# How can I disable an entire select dropdown field after selecting an option through Typescript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, vue.js

What I'm trying to do: If an option is selected in this certain select dropdown, I would like for the entire select dropdown to be disabled.

I'm using Typescript and I'm pretty brand new to it, so I would like to get some insight on how to go about this.

My code currently looks like this:

```html
<button class="button default link small">
  <input
    :id="`item-${index}`"
    :name="`item-${index}`"
    type="checkbox"
    v-model="filteredItems[index].Enabled"
    @change="formUpdated('', index)"
  >
 <label :for="`status-${index}`">Enabled</label>
</button>

<label class="bold">Item Type</label>
  <select required
     v-model="item.Type"
     :disabled="isDisabled(item)"
     @change="changeItemType('', index)"
     @keydown.enter="$event.stopPropagation()"
  >
  <option disabled value="" hidden>Select Item Type</option>
  <option v-for="(value, name) in supportedItems()" :key=value :value=value>{{ name }}</option>
```

```js
<script lang="ts">

private formUpdated(name: string, index: number): void {
    this.$set(this.formChanged, index, name);
}

private changeItemType(name: string, index: number): void {
    this.$set(this.formChanged, index, name);

    const itemType = this.items[index].Type;
    if (itemType === '') {
      this.items[index] = API.StoreInventory.Category.blank();
    } else if (itemType === 'item_1') {
      this.items[index] = API.StoreInventory.Category.blankItem1();
    } else if (itemType === 'item_2') {
      this.items[index] = API.StoreInventory.Category.blankItem2();
    } else if (itemType === 'item_3') {
      this.items[index] = API.StoreInventory.Category.blankItem3();
    } else {
      throw new Error('Item type not found');
    }
  }

private isDisabled(item: ItemCategory<AllItemTypes>): boolean {
    return !item.Enabled;
  }
</script>
```

Note that this is only one field, there are other fields that do not require permanent disabling once an option is selected. There is a button that disables and enables those other fields

So far, I've tried doing

```html
<label class="bold">Item Type</label>
  <select required
     v-model="item.Type"
     :disabled="!value"
     @change="changeItemType('', index)"
     @keydown.enter="$event.stopPropagation()"
  >
  <option disabled value="" hidden>Select Item Type</option>
  <option v-for="(value, name) in supportedItems()" :key=value :value=value>{{ name }}</option>
```

but it disables the entire dropdown before I can select an option. I would like to be able to select an option before it disables the entire dropdown.

I've also tried adding

```html
(document.getElementById('item.type') as HTMLInputElement).disabled = true;
```

to the `changeItemType` method, but since it's attached to the `changeItemType` callback, when I refresh the window, the item becomes enabled after being disabled.

Any idea how I would go about in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could bind `disabled` to a flag that is set in the `change`-event callback:

```html
<template>
  <select :disabled="isDisabled"
          @change="changeItemType('', index)">
    ...
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isDisabled: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeItemType(type, index) {
      //...

      this.isDisabled = true
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/RwKmGKd)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! On the changeItemType method, when I add `this.isDisabled = true`, it says that `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type`. I'm pretty new to typescript in general, my apologies for any noob questions.

Comment: That error looks incomplete. Usually it ends with the type of the variable. But `isDisabled` is clearly Boolean in this example. Can you show the exact code you've used? Or a link to a reproduction (e.g., in GitHub)?

Comment: Hi! I've actually just updated the post, made it more in depth. I've no link to a reproduction, but I do hope the edit is more than enough.

Comment: The code you added doesn't implement what I suggested, as `changeItemType` does not set the `isDisabled` flag.